# Tracing a button in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, single-sign-on

I'm a network engineer and trying to provide an SSO method on a web page. Working on SSO projects i find myself in a continuously learning circle and so far i learnt many things like basic html, js and http protocol.

Anyway, the web page written with ExtJS and as you might guess there are a couple of input boxes and a button below of them. I'm not familiar of the ExtJS and when i look at the source codes, i couldn't find the event / trigger of the button. While tracing this button, i tried to add break onto code in execution time (Chrome) but the "click" event did not fired up. "mouse down" event helped me to add break on execution of code. But due to lack of knowledge about ExtJS, i could not understand the code. Also this isn't look like a classic html form because there is no "form" related tags. So far, i have managed to fill the input boxes but could not find the right way to invoke that button.

The input boxes on page.

```
<input class="x-input-el x-input-text x-form-field login_input_username_icon" type="text" id="ext-element-19" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="UserName" placeholder="Name">

<div class="x-unsized x-field-input" id="ext-input-3"><input class="x-input-el x-input-password x-form-field login_input_password_icon" type="password" id="ext-element-25" autocapitalize="none" name="Password" placeholder="Password"><div class="x-field-mask" style="display: none !important;" id="ext-element-26"></div><div class="x-clear-icon" id="ext-element-27"></div></div>

<div class="x-unsized x-field-input" id="ext-input-4"><input class="x-input-el x-form-field x-input-text" type="text" id="ext-element-31" autocapitalize="sentences" name="Company" placeholder="Company"><div class="x-field-mask" style="" id="ext-element-32"></div><div class="x-clear-icon" id="ext-element-33"></div></div>
```

These are the Javascript codes to fill those input boxes.

```
document.getElementById('ext-element-19').value="John"
document.getElementById('ext-element-25').value="Secret"
document.getElementById('ext-element-31').value="C-Corp"
```

And The Button:

```
<div class="x-button-normal x-button button_green x-layout-box-item x-stretched" id="btnGo" style="margin: 20px 0px 0px !important;"><span id="ext-element-46" class="x-badge" style="display: none;"></span><span class="x-button-icon x-hidden" id="ext-element-48"></span><span id="ext-element-47" class="x-button-label" style="">Enter</span></div>
```

In the "view" of ExtJS

> ```
>   {
>   xtype: "button",
>   id: "btnGo",
>   text: "Enter",
>   cls: "button_green",
>   margin: "20px 0px 0px 0px"
>   },
> ```

If i can find the proper way to invoke/click that button, i believe that i can inject a javascript code in response time before send it to the client browser.

- How can i go further on my research ?
- How to trace a button in this situation ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for listening for a click event in a classic ExtJS application is most often located in the `controller`. Controller file will certainly contain string `extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'`. Your button has an id (`btnGo`), so most likely the code is responsible for create listener look something like this:

```
...
this.control({
...
  '#btnGo' :{
     click: this.login //method name will may vary
  },
...
});
...
```

In my example,`login` method must contains the logic for sending an authorization request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I've found the piece of code you mentioning and there is a function for my button. 
`btnGo: { tap: "girisYap" }`,
I guess, i have to find the related part of "girisYap" now ?

Comment: yep.  it should be contained in the same controller

Comment: This brings another definition to me, `girisYap: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.checkGirisBilgileri(me)
    }`
This one also brings another one and it looks like this is the code when i click on the button because it is long. `checkGirisBilgileri: function(me) {`
Ok, i'll try to find a way to invoke any of them successfuly.

Comment: Hi again,
While debugging the code, i couldn't managed to pause the execution of the script after adding break on "click()" event this lead me to think the "click()" event could be defined externally and i can call it. I wrote below script to invoke button with "click()" event. 
`var input = document.getElementById("btnGo");
input.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("btnGo").mousedown();
});`
after above definition, i tried to call click() event but i got "Uncaught TypeError: mousedown is not a function". i also tried with events other than mousedown.